# How to have multiple Camel Rest DSL definitions with Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, apache-camel, swagger

I am using Camel 2.16.0 with camel-netty4-http, camel-swagger-java and camel-spring-boot in a Spring-boot application. My SpringBootRouter is configured in the following way:

```
   public void configure() {

    restConfiguration()
    .component("netty4-http")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
    .host("0.0.0.0")
    .contextPath("/")
    .port(port)
    .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
         .apiProperty("api.title", "User API")
         .apiProperty("api.version", "1.2.3")
         .apiProperty("cors", "true");

    rest("/hello").description("Say hello.")
    .produces("application/json")
    .get().description("Get hello.").route().transform(constant("hello"));

    rest("/hi").description("Say hi.")
    .produces("application/json")
    .get().description("Get hi.").route().transform(constant("hi"));
}
```

**How can I have multiple rest definitions with Swagger?** The configuration above gives me just the exception below. However, if I remove the other rest definition *rest("/hi")* then Swagger is working just fine.

The exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:423)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route4 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: Endpoint[http://0.0.0.0:10000/api-doc?httpMethodRestrict=GET]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:81)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter.main(FatJarRouter.java:26)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route4 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: Endpoint[http://0.0.0.0:10000/api-doc?httpMethodRestrict=GET]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3473)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3449)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3379)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3003)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2799)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2818)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2764)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:79)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: It seems to be a camel-spring-boot problem maybe. Can you possible attach your sample project as a ZIP to that CAMEL jira ticket so we can reproduce from it? Or put a project on github or something?

Comment: I posted to the Jira ticket and here's also link for the Github example project: https://github.com/jnupponen/camel-spring-boot-swagger-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that is a bug in Apache Camel. I have logged a ticket:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9247